# How to return error/exception as json object in spring security oauth2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on server to server spring restfull web-services and have written all configuration in spring-security.xml (*my oauth2 jar version is 2.0.10 RELEASE*), so now how to render custom jsp on browser to show this error?

#### Json response while creating token

```
 {
    "access_token": "d7a82d67-228f-459f-bf02-5c3501706c6d",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 29,
    "scope": "read trust write"
 }
```

#### Error XMLformat

```
<oauth>
    <error_description> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext </error_description>
    <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

[I just want to remove this xml response and want my custom error.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLXJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in **web.xml**

```
 <!-- Unauthorized -->
   <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>x.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

 <!-- access forbidden -->
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location> x.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: thanks for reply...but this solution is not working.